# Why is mysqli_num_rows not returning a value?

Tags: php, mysql

This the the code for my website. It is designed to register new users, only a logged in admin can do this. The account is created successfully, but it doesn't seem to be returning a 1 for mysqli_num_rows. I printed the value that num_rows returning and nothing came out, not even a 0. I have worked on this for days, I am very new to coding in php so this is probably a glaring mistake, but I can't see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have search Google, but couldn't find anything.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
    $authority = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['use']);

    $queryCheck = "SELECT `user` FROM `user` WHERE `user`='$user';";
    $resultCheck = mysqli_query($link, $queryCheck);
    $rowCheck = mysqli_num_rows($resultCheck);
    if($rowCheck != 1){
    $query = "INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`, `email`,`user`,`pass`) VALUES ($authority,'$name','$email','$user','$pass');";

    //echo $query;

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $row = mysqli_affected_rows($result);

    if($row == 1){
        echo "User Created Successfully!<br/>";
        echo '<br/><br/><br/><a href="admin.php">Return to Administration Page</a>';

    }else{
        echo "User was not created, Please try again.";
    }
    }else{
        echo 'User already exists.';
    }
}
```

Comment: and what does `var_dump($rowCheck)` return? true/false or 0/1?

Comment: Is your program is able to register any entry to the database after running the above program

Comment: The database is updating correctly and yes $rowCheck does return a 1/0 depending on what mysql finds.

Comment: Just out of curiosity — any thing weird in the logs?

Comment: There are no errors thrown if that is what you mean. I am not sure about the logs. Where would I check?

Comment: $link is the SQL connection variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you have to use mysqli_affected_rows for an insert phrase in mysql.